# certbot dns-cloudflare renewal issue

Tags: dns, certificate, letsencrypt, certbot

I am renewing my letsencrypt certificate using certbot with dns-cloudflare authenticator.

When I original set things up, I used this command:

```
$ certbot certonly --dns-cloudflare --dns-cloudflare-credentials ~/certbot-cloudflare.ini -d dev.newbanking.com
```

And it worked. (And it still works.)

When I manually renew my certificates with this command:

```
$ certbot renew
```

it works too.

However, the automatic renewal does not work. In the syslog, I get this:

```
Jul  9 15:00:21 dev systemd[1]: Starting Certbot...
Jul  9 15:00:23 dev certbot[21649]: Renewal configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/dev.newbanking.com.conf (cert: dev.newbanking.com) produced an unexpected error: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'dns_cloudflare_credentials'. Skipping.
Jul  9 15:00:23 dev certbot[21649]: 0 renew failure(s), 1 parse failure(s)
Jul  9 15:00:23 dev systemd[1]: certbot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul  9 15:00:23 dev systemd[1]: Failed to start Certbot.
Jul  9 15:00:23 dev systemd[1]: certbot.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul  9 15:00:23 dev systemd[1]: certbot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/dev.newbanking.com.conf file looks like this:

```
# renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.30.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/dev.newbanking.com
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.newbanking.com/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.newbanking.com/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.newbanking.com/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.newbanking.com/fullchain.pem

# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
authenticator = dns-cloudflare
account = <this-value-I-have-obscured>
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
dns_cloudflare_credentials = /root/certbot-cloudflare.ini
```

Certbot version:

```
$ certbot --version
certbot 0.30.0
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

This was solved. The problem was that I had two installations of certbot running, one (the newest version) was used from the command line, the other (the oldest version) was triggered by the timer.

The solution was to remove the oldest version, then reinstall the newest version, and then reinstall my certificates.